# Is there way to detour 'assertion failed' error?

Tags: python, opencv

I have been working on opencv with python on my rpi.
I am trying to use a function that requires each parameter to be positive, but I want to put variables that stays in positive range that can be manually changed. However, it keeps returning assertion failed because i guess each parameter can't be confirmed as positive numbers.

Is there any way to make this code working or detour this assertion failed ? Thanks in advance !

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def nothing(x):
    pass

img = cv2.imread('highway2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.createTrackbar('number', 'image', 0, 100, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('quality', 'image', 0, 100, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('mindist', 'image', 0, 100, nothing)


while True:
    n = cv2.getTrackbarPos('number', 'image')
    q = cv2.getTrackbarPos('quality', 'image')
    m = cv2.getTrackbarPos('mindist', 'image')
    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, n, float(q/100), m)
    corners = np.int0(corners)

    for i in corners:
        x,y = i.ravel()
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)

    plt.imshow('image',img),plt.show()

    if cv2.waitKey(0)&0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()



OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (qualityLevel > 0 && minDistance >= 0 && maxCorners >= 0) in goodFeaturesToTrack, file /home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/featureselect.cpp, line 270
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detector1.py", line 21, in <module>
    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, n, float(q/100), m)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/featureselect.cpp:270: error: (-215) qualityLevel > 0 && minDistance >= 0 && maxCorners >= 0 in function goodFeaturesToTrack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you're getting a Python traceback.  That means you can handle this with Python exception handling code.  Try replacing your `goodFeaturesToTrack` line with something like this:

```
try:
    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, n, float(q/100), m)
except cv2.error as e:
    print("goodFeaturesToTrack({}, {}, {}, {}) failed with {}".format(
        gray, n, float(q/100), m), e,
    ))
```

Also note that `float(q/100)` may not do what you think.  If you want to ensure float division (instead of floor/int division), try `q / 100.0` or `float(q) / 100`.

Comment: Oh thank you! Actually I am not familiar with those 'try' and 'exception', so i guess I should study more about that. Also small mistake there with float function. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @Jean-Paul's answer, you could handle this by using a simple if-else block with a `continue` to skip the next statements when the error occurs

```
if m>0 and n>0 and q>0 and gray.shape[0]>0 and gray.shape[1]>0:
   corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, n, float(q/100), m)
else:
   print "incorrect parameters"
   continue
```